# Getting org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: Exception during response processing

Tags: aem

I am getting an intermittent exception "org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: Exception during response processing", when I am trying author any component on my page.

[image]

This error is occurring on an irregular basis, that too for the same component.
I think it's an issue with some open session, But I am not able to debug to find the exact root cause.

Thanks in advance, If anyone can share the direction to debug this issue.

Comment: This is awfully generic and could have a large number of potential causes. Check the error log for a possible root cause.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced the same error on one of our component.

I've tried to debug it by adding this on {author:port}/system/console/slinglog:

Logger: org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations

[image]

By looking at our log, it shows that somehow it is getting a NullPointerException but unable to elaborate the root cause of it.

I've also try to change the blueprint relationships, mixins, and delete some properties of the component but still doesn't help.

I've also tried to delete the node and copy paste other similar node manually just to prove that maybe that node has issue. But the result is the same even with the new node.

So, in the end I just settle on renaming the original node and add "_1" and the error is gone.